# Mistake on the website?, First order ODE, concentration in a tank, with inflow and outflow, constant volume

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose:
• The vat contains 130 gallons of liquid, which never changes.  • Sugar water with a concentration of 5 tablespoons/gallon flows through pipe A into the vat at the rate of 25 gallons/minute.
• Sugar water with a concentration of 2 tablespoons/gallon flows through pipe B into the vat at the rate of 30 gallons/minute.
• The liquid in the vat is kept well-mixed.
• Sugar water leaves the vat through pipe C at the rate of 55 gallons/minute.

Let S(t) represent the number of tablespoons of sugar in the vat at time t, where t is given in minutes.

(A) Write the DE model for the time rate of change of sugar in the vat:
*Answer accepted as correct*
$$\frac{dS}{dt} = 185 — \frac{11}{26}S \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space(1) $$

(B) Solve the differential equation to find the amount of sugar in the vat as a function of time. Your function will have an arbitrary constant K in it. Assume that K > 0.
*Answer accepted as correct*
$$S(t) = 
 K \cdot e^{— \frac{11}{26}t} + \frac{4810}{11} \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space (2)$$

(C) Suppose that there are 22 tablespoons of sugar in the vat at t = 0. How many tablespoons will be present 5 minutes later?

I get $K = -415 \frac{3}{11}$ which of course does not meet the $K>0$ assumption or requirement.

$ S(5) = 387.196$ tablespoons.
**The website says this is incorrect. Should negative K be allowed?  Is there something else I'm missing?**

I'm not aware of any way to algebraically manipulate line (2) to modify it and make K positive.

Some context:  This is a web graded exercise from a Calc. I/ II course.  Most web graded assignments pick different constants to minimize cheating.  I'm thinking the interval is set incorrectly.  If it was set totally incorrect, more users would have complained and the professor or someone would correct the website database.  Most combinations of constants make K > O.  However, given these particular combination of constants and IVP is it possible to find positive K?

Maybe someone can affirm the solution I'm getting is correct?

Comment: It's possible.  I'm not going to burn a guess on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sign of $K$ corresponds to whether the $S(0)$ is greater than or less than the equilibrium quantity of $4810/11$ tablespoons, so you cannot have it be positive for all initial quantities.

If you want $K>0$ to denote initial amounts *less than* the equilibrium solution, then you could just write $$S(t) = \frac{4810}{11} - Ke^{-(11/26)t},$$
but then given an initial quantity $S(0) > 4810/11$, we'd once again have a negative $K$ appear, so this is rather a matter of taste rather than anything important.

In any case, I see nothing wrong with your answer to $(c)$.

Comment: Thanks so much.
Your variation of positive or negative K doesn't affect the answer for part c.

Comment: @nickalh Just one thing to note about (c): I'm assuming you know how the answer system works when I say nothing is wrong there.  If your homework system requires exact answers, then obviously your approximation is wrong simply because it's an approximation, and you'd need to write $S(5)$ exactly.

Comment: Actually, I'm a tutor.  I'm not terribly familiar with this particular web system, but I'll definitely make sure the student considers that option.

Comment: About using -K, of course, duhh, how in the world did I miss that?